# R: cannot install 'rasclass' package on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, linux, gcc, g++, gfortran

I am trying to install 'rasclass' package on R (version 3.2.3) but somehow the installation always fails. The output is too large to be pasted here, but I found something interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302209/building-r-package-getting-error-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran), that might be the key to solve this issue.

Shortly: from the terminal I can see I have gcc-4.8 and 4.9, g++-4.8 and 4.9, and gfortran-4.8. I remeber changing the symbolic links between gcc and g++ to use the "4.9" version. Can not having gfortran-4.9 be a problem? If so, how do I change the symbolc links to this version after downloading?

Finally, I just paste the very last part of the (failed) package installation.

```
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RcppEigen.so] Errore 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RcppEigen’
* installing *source* package ‘MatrixModels’ ...
** package ‘MatrixModels’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘Matrix’ 1.1-4 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.5 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘MatrixModels’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/MatrixModels’
ERROR: dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘RcppEigen’ are not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/lme4’
ERROR: dependencies ‘SparseM’, ‘MatrixModels’ are not available for package ‘quantreg’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/quantreg’
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/pbkrtest’
ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’ are not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/car’
ERROR: dependencies ‘car’, ‘randomForest’ are not available for package ‘rasclass’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rasclass’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmphSiL6j/downloaded_packages’
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it was a problem of gfortran.

I installed the version 4.9 through `sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.9`, tried to reinstall `rasclass` package and all its dependencies, and now it works. As stated in a comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302209/building-r-package-getting-error-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran), I did messed up with the symbolic links of `g++` and `gcc`, to use the 4.9 version, but I did not have the same version of `gfortran`. This seemed to be the key to solve the problem.

Finally, to choose `gcc` an `g++` version, I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version). Hope this can help anybody.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install this package and finally, I succeeded to install rasclass library the second try after to have separately installed libraries *car* and *pbkrtest*

my configuration: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - R 3.2.1 RC - gcc 4.8.4

Comment: I tried to install 'car' package but I still get errors and at the end it does not install. Part of the error (just for 'minqa'dependency, but also for the other dependencies) looks like this:
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [minqa.so] Errore 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/home/umberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/minqa’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status