# gfortran not found when installing r-packages

Tags: r, ubuntu, ld, gfortran

I am repeatedly encountering the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
```

when trying to install a lot of r-packages (e.g. igraph, ergm, blockmodels, and I guess every package that requires gcc and fortran in some way or another)

I run R on Ubuntu Trusty, and I have recently upgraded R from 3.1.0 to 3.3.1.
When on 3.1.0, I had been able to install igraph and ergm (and others) without any problem, but not blockmodels.

I have checked for the presence of libgfortran on my system: it is there. Actually there is more than one version of it (3, 4.7, 4.8) and also libgfortran-dev is installed (multiple versions as well)

Any idea of what is going on?
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302209/building-r-package-getting-error-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran

Comment: thanks! i found there a way to fix it. I'll put it on the body of the question

Comment: Do NOT put the answer in your question! Write an actual answer yourself, and after a short mandatory waiting period, click the check mark.

Comment: The forced `sudo ln -s ...` indicates that something is foul on your system. You should not need it.  There are _thousands_ of us running the prebuilt (and always current) R on Ubuntu via the CRAN mirror.  Not to mention thousands of automated Travis CI runs on trusty (and older ones on precise).  Install R-for-Ubuntu-from-CRAN, and you won't need any ugly gymnastics potentially creating worse longer term problems on your box.

Comment: @joran: maybe, but not in this case as it really is not a good answer.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I see what you mean. But I have exactly done what you say: install R for Ubuntu from CRAN. I also tried to purge it and install it back, but the problem remained. I would really like to have a 'cleaner' way to fix the problem, the point is that i have not found it

Comment: Do you have the `r-base-dev` package installed?  It is meant to pull in all required dependencies.

Comment: yes, I have it. I tried to remove and install that as well...

Comment: Then go down the line. Looks at `gcc --version` and make sure have the same verson of the Fortran compiler installed.  This is _still the wrong place for this discussion_.

Answer (score 1):

In Arch Linux, the gfortran package is named gcc-fortran. To install it:

```
sudo pacman -S gcc-fortran
```