# DESeq2 - RcppArmadillo error

Tags: r, bioinformatics

When I am trying to install `RcppArmadillo` `BiocLite` library in `R`, it is giving me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/home/nikita/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RcppArmadillo’
```

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`, `R - 3.2.5` and `g++-5.4`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a similar question on `stackoverflow`:

[Building R package getting error "ld: cannot find -lgfortran "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302209/building-r-package-getting-error-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran)

and the solution was to create a symlink as described by `kevin` there:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 /usr/lib/libgfortran.so
```

Comment: the question should be marked as duplicate, I suppose.