# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran

Tags: r, shared-libraries, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install an R package, See the code below:

```
>  install.packages("mnormt")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/mnormt_1.5-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 37169 bytes (36 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 36 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mnormt’ ...
** package ‘mnormt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c biv-nt.f -o biv-nt.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c sadmvnt.f -o sadmvnt.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o mnormt.so biv-nt.o sadmvnt.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'mnormt.so' failed
make: *** [mnormt.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/mnormt’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpQnOaAx/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("mnormt") :
  installation of package ‘mnormt’ had non-zero exit status
```

But I have already installed gfortran library. Still this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building R package and error "ld: cannot find -lgfortran"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6302209/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suspicion is that you have installed `libgfortran3` but not `libgfortran-5-dev`. The latter is required for building things using the library. The best solution in that case would be

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

This will install `libgfortran-5-dev` and any other packages that are strictly necessary for building CRAN packages.

Alternatively you could also use

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-mnormt
```

and skip the binary installation.

Comment: Thanks I got it! @Ralf

Comment: I faced same error and eventually `~$ sudo apt-get install libgfortran-*` to install all versions to cope with it. these `sudo apt-get install r-cran-mnormt` very useful which can let us install through terminal :)