# R devtools package installation fails to find openssl

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the devtools package for R (v3.6.1) with `install.package("devtools")`. The install fails when openssl cannot be found, although `openssl version -a` indicates that LibreSSL 2.8.3 is installed. The OS is macOS 10.15.1.

Here is the console log:

```
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Homebrew 2.2.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 434f; last commit 2019-12-03)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision deedf; last commit 2019-12-03)
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
```

How do I exactly do that PATH stuff the error message suggests? Or is there any other remedy you could suggest? Both the r and macOS installations are fresh, so there shouldn't be anything out of the ordinary messing this up.

Comment: As LibreSSL is a fork of OpenSSL, I presume they are different enough to not be recognized by `devtools` package as Openssl. You should try to install `openssl@1.1` as suggested by the console log.

Comment: This solves the problem, thank you very much! I didn't initially want to try this over concerns that the native ssl would get replaced. However, `brew install openssl` left the original intact and devtools installation finished successfully. @dc37 if you wanna write up an answer, I'll make sure to accept it.

Comment: Glad that you get it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As LibreSSL is a fork of OpenSSL, I presume they are different enough to not be recognized by devtools package as Openssl. You should try to install openssl@1.1 as suggested by the console log.

```
brew install openssl
```