# Installing R package from CRAN archive has non-zero exit status

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I need to install *fwildclusterboot*, a package that has been removed from CRAN.

I tried installing it as follows:

```
library(devtools)
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fwildclusterboot/fwildclusterboot_0.9.tar.gz")
```

However, I end up getting the following error message at the end of the installation process (I have a MacBook, MacOS Monterey 12.5.1, and my RStudio is version 2022.07.1):

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [fwildclusterboot.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fwildclusterboot’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/fwildclusterboot’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/1n/m1g55_416rj6m4w3v6v9x2340000gn/T//RtmppWJnds/fileaae0dc5e6aa/fwildclusterboot_0.9.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302209/building-r-package-and-error-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran) may be relevant.

Comment: There is a discussion here: https://www.cynkra.com/blog/2021-03-16-gfortran-macos/

Comment: Hi, I am the author of fwildclusterboot. Sorry for the inconvenience! The short story is that fwildclusterboot was archieved because a dependency failed a test and I did not manage to drop the dependency AND pass all CRAN tests on time. In the meantime, you can download a compiled version of fwildclusterboot for Mac from r-universe via `install.packages('fwildclusterboot', repos ='https://s3alfisc.r-universe.dev')`. Best, Alex

Comment: @A.Fischer, thanks a lot for your answer, no inconvenience at all! I managed to use the package thanks to what hiyorjil proposed below. I look forward to having fwildclusterboot back in CRAN! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem some months before, this is the easy way,
Go to: https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases an you'll find the lastest version for Monterey with an easy installer (.dmg), select depending if you have an ARM or Intel based computer.