# installing the package fwildclusterboot

Tags: r

I have troubles with installing the package  fwildclusterboot. It says that it is no longer available in CRAN.  Also didn't succeed even when I exploited it from the archive. I was searching for some new version but could not find it.

Can you please help me how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019208/installing-r-package-from-cran-archive-has-non-zero-exit-status ?  Can you please tell us what OS you're using, what you tried, and precisely what "didn't succeed" means (e.g. cut and paste error messages)?

Comment: You would need to go to the [archive repository](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fwildclusterboot/) and download the latest version, and then install it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of fwildclusterboot.

Due to issues with a broken dependency I did not manage to fix on time, fwildclusterboot is temporarily not available on CRAN. The long story is that a dependencies' dependency failed a test, then the dependency was not fixed, therefore archived on CRAN, and I did not manage to a) drop the dependency on time and pass all CRAN notes within the given two-three week time limit. Now I am trying to bring the package back, but CRAN is not very responsive towards me.

In the meantime, you can download the package from [R universe](https://s3alfisc.r-universe.dev/ui#package:fwildclusterboot) (a CRAN alternative, set up by rOpensci) by running `install.packages('fwildclusterboot', repos ='https://s3alfisc.r-universe.dev')`. I hope the package will be back on CRAN soon!